# Unity UI fixed child size in horizontal layout

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build the clone layout of wechat. But I not able to make build the correct alignment for the children inside of Horizontal Layout. The parent of the horizontal layout is ScrollView.

The video link below shows the effect I get for now. The avatar should be fixed. I did tried to apply some others Layout but it's not working very well for me.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16nSz6x-Ojh_GqrnWFKdJwbYSZ396g8CP/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because your UI anchors are on incorrect position. You need to understand the UI anchor system of Unity first. Take a look at this official article [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UIBasicLayout.html).

Comment: It's not able to set anchor if the parent is Horizontal Layout. But not sure why it works now. Not sure why I put the UI -> Image but not able to resize it to the square by entering 100 x 100 in scales.

Comment: is it solved or you still have problem? I did not get you.

Comment: It solved but i didnt changed any anchor since its parent using the horizontal layout. Not sure how it get fixed.